# Construction of a Covering Space by 'Twisting'

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

I have a question about the explanantion of the idea behind
the classiyfing spaces $BG$ with respect (topological) group $G$.
In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space#Formalism) is stated that

> The classifying property required of $BG$ in fact relates to
> $\pi: EG \to BG$. We must be able to say that given any principal $G$-bundle

$$  \gamma: Y \to Z $$

> over a (nice enough) space $Z$, there is a classifying map $\phi$
> from $Z$ to $BG$, such that $\gamma$ is the pullback of $\pi$ along $\phi$.
> In less abstract terms, the construction of $\gamma$ by 'twisting' should be
> reducible via $\phi$ to the twisting already expressed by the
> construction of $\pi$.

Question: In this less formal explanation is used the word
'twisting'. What does it mean to say informaly in context of topology or more
concretely the theory
of covering spaces to construct a cover or principal $G$-bundle
by a 'twisting'? What is here this 'twisting' procedure concretely? Does it refer to cocycles $U_i \cap U_j \to G$ which 'encode' $Y$ and $Z= \bigcup_i U_i$? Or is it something else?

Comment: Do you see how a Mobius band is a normal band, but with the line segments "twisted" as they go around in a circle?

Comment: Yes, so here is 'twisting' is naively described as abstract 'constrain' for a $G$-bundle to become trivial? And to draw analogy to Mobius band the 'twist' might be see as something which measures how 'far' away the bundle is from beeing trivial, right? That's all?

Comment: In fact, I know that a $G$-bundle can be completely described by compatible cocycle maps $U_i \cap U_j \to G$ and I heard that they are sometimes described to contain some 'twist' which should reflect roughly this intuition with Moebuis band....